# How to saturate memory bus

Tags: c, optimization, memory, hardware

I want to test a program with various memory bus usage levels. For example, I would like to find out if my program works as expected when other processes use 50% of the memory bus. 
How would I simulate this kind of disturbance?

My attempt was to run a process with multiple threads, each thread doing random reads from a big block of memory. This didn't appear to have a big impact on my program. My program has a lot of memory operations, so I would expect that a significant disturbance will be noticeable.
I want to saturate the bus but without using too many CPU cycles, so that any performance degradation will be caused only by bus contention.

Notes:

- I'm using a Xeon E5645 processor, DDR3 memory

Comment: You should define what platform you use and what type of memory. Is it a 8bit 8051, an ARM-Cortex M3 or an Intel Core-i7? That could make a little difference

Answer (score 3):

The mental model of "processes use 50% of the memory bus" is not a great one.  A thread that has acquired a core and accesses memory that's not in the caches uses the memory bus.

Getting a thread to saturate the bus is simple, just use memcpy().  Copy several times the amount that fits in the last cache and warm it up by running it multiple times so there are no page faults to slow the code down.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct would be to set up a bunch of DMA operations to bounce data around without using the CPU too much. This all depends on what operating system you're running and what hardware. Is this an embedded system? I'd be glad to give more detail in the comments.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try. I'm using a Xeon E5645 processor, Fedora Linux

Comment: Hmm, actually, if I do DMA, wouldn't it use a different bus than my program?

Comment: No, it's sort of a seperate core within the processor, it uses the same memory bus (unless you've got some wierd dual-port memory, which you probably don't for a Xeon). Note that it very likely bypasses your CPU Cache, so it'll only really impact performance for cache misses.

Comment: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html

This should get you started with setting up DMA. You'll probably need to write a module, i don't think there's a way to do it in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SSE2 movntps instructions to stream data, to avoid cache conflicts for the other thread in the same core. Maybe unroll that loop 16 times to minimize number of instructions per memory transfer. While DMA idea sounds good, the linked manual is old and for 32bit linux and your processor model makes me think you probably have 64bit os, which makes me wonder how much of it is correct still. And bug in your test code may screw your hard drive in worst case.